# Count total price of items with php

Tags: php, mysql

I Create a simple php shopping cart :

- Add product with quantity.
- update quantity of product.

I want to count total price of all items in cart but I don't know how ?

I display items with this code :

```
<?php
session_start();
$where = implode(",",$_SESSION['product']);
    $get_p = $mysqli->prepare("select id,name,price,imgs,quantity from products where id IN ($where)");
    $get_p->execute();
    $get_p->bind_result($id,$name,$price,$imgs,$quantity);
    $get_p->store_result();
    while($get_p->fetch()) {
    $qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$id];
    $total = $qty * $price;
?>
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgs);  ?>"/></td>
<td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);  ?></td>
<td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($price)."×".$qty;  ?></td>
<td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>"  min="1" name="qty_cart"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete<?php echo $id; ?>"/></td>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["delete".$id])) {
unset($_SESSION['product'][$id]);
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
}

?>
</table>
<div class="price_all_items">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: You are using prepared statements incorrectly. `select sum(price) where id = ?`

Comment: What you mean I use prepared statements incorrectly.

Comment: select sum(price) this just get the price of item but i want total price of items multiple quantity

Comment: @Mouradkaroudi you're not using the preperation. You could just use a $mysqli_query

Comment: You need to use placeholders for the actual values. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php Then bind them. Multiply the quant by the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this part of your code

```
while($get_p->fetch()) {
    $qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$id];
    $total = $qty * $price;
```

with this

```
$totalSum = 0;
while($get_p->fetch()) {
    $qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$id];
    $total = $qty * $price;
    $totalSum += $total;
```

and after you end of your loop the value in `$total` will have total amount.

Comment: No men this code just get the total price of one item I want get the total price of all items in the cart

Comment: So I didn't understand your query correctly. Check my answer again.

Comment: No :D
Look I have iphone [price : 199 , quantity : 2].
And I have Ipad[price : 200 , quantity : 3].
The total price of iphone is : 398.
The total price of ipad is : 600
I want the total price of this two items
I want variable to display : 998

Comment: Look again at my proposal - after your loop in $total value you will have what you need. Look that there is += so the $total will increase by $qty * $price for every product in your while loop. With your example: $total = 0, then $total = $total + 199 * 2 (after it you have 398 in $total), then for the next product you will have again $total = $total + 200 * 3 (so $total will be equal to 398 + 600). What is wrong with my answer if you say that is not correct?

Comment: Your code is display every product total price I want to count all prices * their quantity

Comment: Put var_dump($total) just after close brace of the while loop (with my code) and tell me what value do you have there. Is it total price for one product (for example the last one) or for all of them?

Comment: I have the total price of each one alone

Comment: Yes yes I have the total items price and the last one price how to fetch just the total

Comment: So is my proposal works as you need? If yes then please mark my answer as correct. If not please tell my what is wrong with the result and I will try to do more to help you.

Comment: Yes bro your code is works ! but just the var display the total price of all items and the total price of last one. I want just  display the total items price

Comment: But my code don't display anything for any product in loop. Only the var_dump after loop can do this (remove this var_dump if you saw that there is total price for all products). I see your code form the question and you never use $total variable to display its value in html. If you want the total value for every product and total for all of them then look at my answer (I've edit it again). In loop you can use the $total value and to display whole amount use the $totalSum after loop.